# Is there a better way to log failures in a chain of Java Vavr Try clauses?

Tags: java, try-catch, fluent, flatmap, vavr

I'm trying to log at each failure stage and, as far as I can tell, I need to nest the try and log inside a flatmap.

```
Try.of(() -> true).
    onFailure(h -> System.out.println("first onFailure")).
    flatMap(i -> Try.of(() -> { throw new RuntimeException(); }).
                     onFailure(j -> System.out.println("second onFailure"))).
    flatMap(k -> Try.of(() -> true).
                     onFailure(l -> System.out.println("third onFailure")));
```

Is there an easier way to do it than the above? Is there a function in the library that I can use to replace the nested `Try.of()`s?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you nest the `onFailure` calls? How about this syntax?

```
Try.of(() -> true)
        .onFailure(h -> System.out.println("first onFailure"))
        .flatMap(i -> Try.of(() -> { throw new RuntimeException(); }))
        .onFailure(j -> System.out.println("second onFailure"))
        .flatMap(k -> Try.of(() -> true)
        .onFailure(l -> System.out.println("third onFailure")));
```

Comment: If I read what you have written correctly, if the of() 'throws' then this will log three times, which I don't want to do

Comment: My bad. Then I don't think it's possible. Unless you're willing to do some kind of pattern matching once and for all in an `onFailure` after the flatmaps (e.g. using `recover`), your workflow is not linear short circuiting in case of error (and flatmap is useful for this).

Answer (score 0):

If you want just log failures you can do it once:

```
Try.of(() -> method1())
        .mapTry(i -> method2())
        .mapTry(k -> method3())
        .onFailure(throwable -> log.error("Something wrong", throwable));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to be able to log the failures per sub-clause instead of on the entire statement

Comment: @RichardPolton Just edited answer.
As I see it, exception's stack trace can show wich sub-clause failed.
But if you want more control, you should use nested Try.of()